# Compiler flag to prevent partial redundancy elimination in gfortran

Tags: gfortran

I'm trying to get a little more speed out of a large Fortran program I'm working with.  I'm not (yet) intimately familiar with the code so I thought compiler optimization would be a good first stop. Using gfortran's `-O1` option is fine but `-O2` and `-O3` produced runtime errors in the form of unexpected NaN's. By breaking `-O2` down into its constituent flags, I determined that `-ftree-pre` was the problem and everything else works fine.

Is there a way of suppressing just the `-ftree-pre` flag? That way I can compile with `-O3 -no-ftree-pre`, if that makes sense.

I've already determined which part of the code is producing the error, so my long term plan is to eliminate the error. But this will constitute a quick fix for now.

Comment: The negative version of `-f<something>` is `-fno-<something>`. In your case the option is `-fno-tree-pre` and it has to be supplied after `-O3` as you've guessed correctly.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev. If you make that into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: There you go. I'm glad that I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the GCC manual page:

> Many options have long names starting with `-f` or with `-W` - for example, `-fmove-loop-invariants`, `-Wformat` and so on. Most of these have both positive and negative forms; the negative form of `-ffoo` would be `-fno-foo`. This manual documents only one of these two forms, whichever one is not the default.

In your case, in order to negate the effect of `-O3` enabling `-ftree-pre`, you should append `-fno-tree-pre` **after** the `-O3` flag.